# How to get an array of elements of one model from the form asp.net core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I need to get an array of elements of one model from the form. Then return the same array back to shape.
Model:

```
public class Check
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Text { get; set; }

    public int Number1 {get; set;}
    public int Number2 {get; set;}
}
```

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Check(string tema)
    {
        IEnumerable<Check> less = _context.Checks.Where(e => e.Text == tema);

        return View(less);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Check(IEnumerable<Check> Checks)
    {   
        return View(Checks);
    }
```

Form:

```
@model IEnumerable<Check>

@foreach (var check in Model)
{
 <form asp-action="Check" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
  <p>@check?.Text</p>
   <p><input type="text"asp-for="@check.Number1"/></p>

  @if(Number1 == Number2)
   {<p>ok</p>}
 
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Ok" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
  </form>
  }
```

I have everything working for one model, and if I pass an array, I get an empty form. How to fix it?

Comment: Are you saying the form when first rendered is empty? Or, the form submitted back to the controller is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.If you just want to post **single model**, but the backend you want receive the `IEnumerable<Check>`, you need add name attribute(`name="[0].propertyName"`) to override the `asp-for` generated `name="check.propertyName"`

2.For your code, it will generate **multiple forms** with submit button. If you want to post an array model, you need move `<form>` and submit button outside foreach loop.

3.If post array model from view to controller. The `IEnumerable<Check> Checks` is a list model, so the model binding system would find the name by `[i].propertyName`.

4.`<p>` element text cannot passed to backend by form submit. If you want to post it, try to add a hidden input.

If post **array model** from view to controller, change your view like below:

```
@model IEnumerable<Check>
@{
    int i=0;  //add this...
}
<form asp-action="Check" asp-controller="Home" method="post">
    @foreach (var check in Model)
    {
      <p>
          @check?.Text                                  
          <input type="text"asp-for="@check.Text" name="[@i].Text" hidden/>  @* //add the hidden input*@
      </p>  
                                                     //add the name...
       <p><input type="text"asp-for="@check.Number1" name="[@i].Number1"/></p>

      @if(check.Number1 == check.Number2)
       {<p>ok</p>}
      
        i++;  //add this...
    }
    <div class="form-group">
         <input type="submit" value="Ok" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
```

---

If you **post single model**, change your view like below:

```
@foreach (var check in Model)
{
    <form asp-action="Check " asp-controller="Home" method="post">

    <p>
      @check?.Text                                  
      <input type="text"asp-for="@check.Text" name="[0].Text" hidden/>  @* //add the hidden input*@
    </p>  
                                                  @*add the name...*@
    <p><input type="text"asp-for="@check.Number1" name="[0].Number1"/></p>

     @if(check.Number1 == check.Number2)
     {<p>ok</p>}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Ok" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</form>
}
```